# Set State Type Narrowing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a functional component with props passed from SSR (nextJS), with a state inside as follows:

```
const Component = ({err, n}: {err?: ErrorType, n?: N})=>{
    const [x, setX] = useState(n || null)
    ...
    if(err){
        return <ErrorComponent err={err}>
    }
    else if(!(x===null)){
        return <SomeComponent setX={setX}>
    }
}
```

`x` can be seen to be of type `N | null`. However, after the "type narrowing" if condition, while the type of `x` is now `N`, the type of `setX` is still `Dispatch<SetState<N | null>>`. However, SomeComponent expects that the type of `setX` is `Dispatch<SetState<N>>`.

How can I force the type narrowing, without having to use a type assertion?

I have also tried this, but React is throwing a `React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.` error.

```
const Component = ({err, n}: {err?: ErrorType, n?: N})=>{
    if(err || !n){
        return <ErrorComponent err={err}>
    }
    const [x, setX] = useState(n)
    return <SomeComponent setX={setX}>
}
```

Comment: Instead of `null` use a different fallback value that is assignable to `N`.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is working as intended. It's not narrowing the type because it wouldn't be safe to do so.

`Dispatch<SetState<N>>` is not assignable to `Dispatch<SetState<N | null>>`. Let's break that down.

`Dispatch<SetState<N>>` is equivalent to `((action: N | ((prevValue: N) => N)) => void`.

`(action: N) => void` is assignable to `(action: N | null) => void` but `(action: (prevValue: N) => N) => void` is not assignable to `(action: (prevValue: N | null) => N | null) => void`.

`x` being non-null does not imply `setX` will provide a non-null value as `prevValue` because `x` could be stale. The two types are independent in that regard.

---

If you can get away with not using set state actions you can type the `setX` prop as `(action: N) => void`. That way it's assignable to `Dispatch<SetState<N | null>>`. The downside of course is `SomeComponent` cannot call `setX` with a function.

---

If you need to use function set state actions in `SomeComponent` you'll have to pass in a function that does the runtime type checks before calling the action callback to make it actually type safe.

The following extension of `setX` replaces the type unsafe call with a no-op update instead.

```
const typeSafeSetX = (action: SetState<N | null>) => typeof action === 'function' ? setX(prevValue => prevValue === null ? prevValue : action(prevValue)) : setX(action);
```

I wouldn't recommend you do this as it's only replacing one bad behaviour with another.